# iPhone View Controller Register

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Hi i'm pretty new to iPhone development, looking to put together a fairly substantial app and just wondering should View Controllers which are used later in the lifecycle of the app be registered in the AppDelegate at the start of just introduced as needed?

For example I start with a login page which requires a UINavigationController so I register with AppDelegate and i'm away, however following an intermediary page I'm 
using a TabController so do I just introduce it on the 3rd page or register in AppDelegate?

More of an architectural best practice issue really :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to answer your question short and simple. iPhone apps should use the least amount of memory as possible. So introducing a View Controller when needed is much less memory consuming then keeping everything open and running from start to end.
Hope that answers your question.

Comment: If your question is answered you could check the "v" in this post, so other people know they don't have to answer anymore.. :)

Answer (score 6):

When the app launches, the main xib is loaded.
We basically provide the very first vie/view controller when the app launches in the app delegate in the function

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

This very first view controller could be UIViewController, UITabBarController, UINavigationController, etc. In short, any view controller.

From here, your application can proceed by showing new/other view controllers one after another in various ways like presenting a view controller modally, pushing a view controller (in case of UINavigationController), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should only instanciate classes that you need to save memory. If you create you views in code, a good way to do so is to use the getter method of a @property to create the class. For example, if you have a header file with:

```
@interface MyClass
   @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *myView; 
@end
```

And an implementation file:

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize myView;

- (UIView *)myView {
   if (myView == nil) {
      myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
      // do more initializations
   }
   return myView;
}
```

Then you can just access the view at any time, if it hasn't been created it will be, e.g.

```
[superView addSubView:self.myView];
```